# Find all the initial values that satisfy a limit property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all the initial values for the IVP $x'=x^2(x^2-4)$ such that, for the solution x(t), $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=\infty$. I know that the solution is $x(t)>2$, but I'm unsure of how to arrive at this solution.

Comment: Hint: The equation has 3 singular points at $x=-2,0,2$

Comment: Would we have to find the series solution for this?

Comment: No. It's just a very simple fact that the solution can only exist in one of 4 intervals: $(-\infty,-2)$, $(-2,0)$, $(0,2)$ and $(2,\infty)$. The initial condition determines which interval it is. So if you want $x(t)\to \infty$, you'll first need $x(t_0) > 2$. You'll also need $x'(t) > 0$, but this is guaranteed.